# How to perform spreadsheet like vertical lookup in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a `collection1` with `collection1Column` and another column`presentInCollection2`,

```
--------------------------------------------
| collection1Column | presentInCollection2 |
--------------------------------------------
| A                 | null                 |
| B                 | null                 |
| C                 | null                 |
--------------------------------------------
```

I have a `collection2` with `collection2Compare`

```
----------------------
| collection2Compare |
---------------------- 
| A                  | 
| B                  | 
----------------------
```

Now I need to update `collection1`'s column `presentInCollection2` only if an exact match of `collection1Column` is found in `collection2`'s `collection2Compare`.

One possible javascript solution I have thought is the following:

- Get all the values from both the collections in 2 variables.
- Once the values are available, take up one by one values from `collection1`'s `collection1Column`  and iterate on `collection2Compare` of `collection2` to find a match.
- Once the match is found, will update the `presentInCollection2`

This looks very expensive in terms of memory and performance to me.

However, I'm looking for a database only implementation for match and updates, etc.

Please suggest!

> In simple words, how to do [V Lookup](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/vlookup/how-to-pull-values-from-another-worksheet-in-excel) in `MongoDB`?

Comment: Why tag excel? vlookup works fine in excel...

Comment: @SolarMike Was trying to connect the concept of excel vlookup to this. Removed anyways

Comment: MongoDB has [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which meets your requirements. With `$out` we can override `collection1`

Comment: @Valijon can you please give an example? I am unable to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform MongoDb Aggregation with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator. It does *left outer join* and returns `Array`. In the next step, we need to use `$arrayElemAt` to get a single value.

```
Collection1Model.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      localField: "collection1Column",
      foreignField: "collection2Compare",
      as: "presentInCollection2"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      presentInCollection2: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$presentInCollection2.collection2Compare",
              [
                null
              ]
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  //,{"$out" : "collection1"}
]).exec();
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8wcBLSBIaIa)

**Note:** If we add as the last step `{$out:"collection1"}`, MongoDB will override all records with aggregation result.

Comment: this is the perfect example! Thanks a ton for your help!